# Issue when using laravel forge with bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, forge, laravel-forge

When using bitbucket with forge, you have to follow this message in order to use bitbucket and forge

> When using a custom Git deployment or Bitbucket, you must add the following SSH key to your source control provider before installing repositories:

The problem is it's not clear where I need to put the SSH key, there's like a million place in bitbucket that you could add a SSH key to, so please can someone **explain to me why when using bitbucket I need to add SSH keys** and where I need put them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ssh keys on your bitbucket account.

```
bitbucket account-> Settings->SSH Keys
```

> Bitbucket Server administrators can set up SSH access keys to secure
> the Git operations that other systems perform on the repositories
> managed in Bitbucket Server.
>
> Using access keys avoids the need to
> store user credentials on another system, and means that the other
> system doesn't have to use a specific user account in Bitbucket
> Server.
>
> For example, access keys can be used to allow your build and
> deploy server to authenticate with Bitbucket Server to check out and
> test source code.

Reference:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-add-an-SSH-key-as-opposed-to-a-deployment-keys/qaq-p/413373

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/ssh-access-keys-for-system-use-776639781.html

[image]

Comment: @Mohammadhayajneh https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html

Comment: I do not know about git process but you can check my updated answer why bitbucket use SSH

Comment: @Mohammadhayajneh `github` uses both `ssh` and `https`. If you use `ssh` then you must have to supply `ssh key` and in case of `https` you can access `github` using `username` and `password`